# Automatically do ThenInclude if there is any ICollection in Include

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following code:

```cs
public async Task<T?> SingleOrDefaultClientWhereAndSelect<T>(
    Expression<Func<Client, bool>> where, 
    Expression<Func<Client, T>> select,
    List<Expression<Func<Client, object>>> includes
)
{
    if (where is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(where), "where was null");
    if (select is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(select), "select was null");

    var query = _configurationDbContext.Clients.Where(where);

    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
        query.Include(include);
    }

    return await query.Select(select).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

And when I call Include in foreach loop, I also want to load all ICollections (with ThenInclude) related to included object. How can I do it, if I don't know type of included object?

Comment: Curiously, that `Select` discards all Includes. It is mutual exclusive operators. So why do you need Includes?

Comment: You could look into [Explicit Data Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit), by using the `.LoadAsync()` method and using reflection on the type

Comment: Due to performance issues caused by `LoadAsync`, I changed my entities and their relationships. So my function looks like this: https://pastebin.com/VQB0Gfis. Thanks you.